# A "Quick Access Toolbar" for a winforms window?

Tags: .net, winforms, toolbar, ribbon

For a small program that I am developing, I decided it's best to implement a Quick Access Toolbar (like those that come with Ribbon controls (office 2007, 2010?)).
Now my problem is that I cannot find any free Ribbon control for winforms from which I could extract the toolbar.

I have a pseudo-QAC at the moment but there is a rendering issue with the standard toolbar.

So can anyone show me a good implementation for this control? It must be OS-independent. (No DWM-only non-client are removing.)

---

For others, this is my result:

In a new form, I add the following code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var cp = base.CreateParams; // Retrieve the normal parameters.
        cp.Style = 0x40000000 | 0x4000000; // WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
        cp.ExStyle &= 0x00080000; // WS_EX_LAYERED
        cp.Parent = GetDesktopWindow(); // Make "GetDesktopWindow()" from your own namespace.
        return cp;
    }
}
```

And then place a toolbox with a style provided by Cody Gray, and I always move this form with it's owner and now I have a quick access toolbar! :D

Comment: If you're looking for a solution that doesn't require drawing in the non-client area, why not just use the `ToolStrip` control to create a standard toolbar? Maybe you can explain more about the "rendering issue" that you're experiencing?

Comment: Ok, when mouse-over-ing a toolbar item, a blue rectangle with darker borders is placed before it. With my solution, the lower border of that rectangle is invisible, because it is beneath a panel.

Comment: Have you tried changing the z-order of the controls? You could put the panel behind the toolbar.

Comment: The toolbar is inside a panel so I can hide the lower part of it, which is a white line. (always different from the background color so I cannot make it transparent)

Comment: You are truly obsessed with this crazy floating form approach aren't you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather in reading the comments, you are looking for a simple toolbar control that provides a quick way for the user to perform common tasks/operations. However, unlike the Quick Access Toolbar included in a Microsoft Office-style Ribbon, you don't want a solution that requires drawing in the non-client area because this solution is not portable. Drawing in the non-client area requires rolling out completely custom window chrome, which isn't going to work seamlessly across all versions of Windows (because of DWM and a host of other reasons).

I suggested using the standard [`ToolStrip` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.aspx) provided in the Framework, but you expressed concern that it draws a white line underneath it and said that when you try to hide this white line by placing it inside a panel, the highlight border (which you want) gets covered as well.

**Therefore, I propose a couple of possible solutions:**

**1.** The `ToolStrip`'s bottom white border only gets drawn when its [`RenderMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.rendermode.aspx) is set to "System". You can set it to "Professional" instead and banish the white line forever, while retaining the darkened hover border effect.

**2.** If you don't like the "Professional" rendering style and want to stick with "System", you can simply inherit off of the existing [`ToolStripSystemRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsystemrenderer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and stop it from drawing the bottom white border:

```
public class CorrectedToolStripRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //do nothing here
    }
}
```

And then simply set the `ToolStrip` control to use your custom renderer, like so:

```
myToolStrip.Renderer = new CorrectedToolStripRenderer();
```

**3.** You can implement a *completely* custom renderer for the `ToolStrip`, derived directly from the base [`ToolStripRenderer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.aspx), and define for yourself exactly how you want it to look.

For example, because I hate controls that don't look like standard Windows UI elements, I have a custom renderer that I use to ensure menus and toolbars in all of my WinForms applications are painted just like those in the OS. ("System" doesn't get it anywhere close to right in Vista/7.) Mine is a heavily-modified version of [this sample](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid66C03CEC25A1169F4366316D885E63196EDFE312.aspx?s=nativemethods#L25).

Others (here's looking at you, Office team) absolutely love a custom UI, and this way allows you to really go all out and match the appearance of your application. For example, here are custom renderers that look like [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3780996) or [Office 2007](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3685172) to get you started. A Google search will turn up tons more.